# Clauses with "like" and "than"

Tags: phrases, verbs, phrase-usage

> - *He runs just like his brother.*
> - *He runs just like his brother does.*
> - *He runs just like his brother runs.*

Which sentence is grammatically correct. Also, what about these three?:

> - *He runs better than his brother.*
> - *He runs better than his brother does.*
> - *He runs better than his brother runs.*

I'm really having trouble with sentences like these. Although it seems like all options would be accepted in everyday conversation, which is grammatically correct? Is the second verb even needed?

Comment: 'Grammatically correct' is not easy to define in grey areas such as these. Is 'He looks just like his brother' more correct than 'He runs just like his brother'? Is 'just like' more acceptable than 'like' as a substitute for 'in the same way that'? Who is giving you trouble here? I'd not be fazed by any of the above in conversation, but would probably choose the 'does' versions in more formal situations. I'd normally avoid the versions repeating 'runs' on stylistic grounds.

Answer (score 1):

All six sentences are grammatically correct.

The second and third in each set of three are merely adverb clauses, which are clauses (they each have a subject and a predicate) that function as adverbs (whoa).

The first sentence of each group is what is known as an elliptical clause, characterized by the [ellipsis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCrP6r4-PTAhUi6IMKHe3SAygQFgg1MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEllipsis&usg=AFQjCNEznM2P8cWvJDWeevj_b0XVIPlvxQ&sig2=PSt5w1B40UO8FpiABrJfhw) of the predicate. From context, the verb *runs* or *does* (these are interchangeable here) is implied, though it never appears in the clause, giving the impression of incompleteness.